# Need to trigger dag after completing of 2 parallel dags

Tags: airflow

Can any one please advise me to solve this problem **I have 3 dags and I want to trigger the dag after the completion of 2 parallel dags**

Even though they start at the same time these 2 parallel dags will end at different times.

Comment: Why not combine the DAGs into one dag?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be using `external_task_sensor`. 
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html

> Waits for a different DAG or a task in a different DAG to complete for a
>       specific execution_date

In your third DAG (C), you would need two sensors, one for each dependent DAGs (A and B).

sensorTask_A >> Task_C

sensorTask_B >> Task_C

Comment: Could you please share the DAG code or sample code? Thanks!